# Is there a free jquery slideshow that will do this?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have a homepage that has a section dedicated to a "slideshow". It looks like this:

[image]

Each of the three bars at the right corresponds to an image. When the user stays on the page long enough without clicking anywhere, the images should start rotating automatically, but the user should also be able to click on one of the bars and display the corresponding image.

The closest plugin I was able to find that would handle the vertical bars is [SlideDeck](http://www.slidedeck.com/), but that's a commercial plugin and this site is for a non-profit that doesn't have a budget for these kind of things.

Comment: This is just a stylistic variation on the pager links in jQuery Cycle: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html -- use CSS to style the pager links with your images.

Comment: That would probably work. I'm sure I'm making this more difficult that it needs to be; I'm a server-side programmer and am just getting my feet wet with jquery.

Comment: @mblase75  OK, where exactly can I make style changes to the pager links? The example you provide gives a few lines of style for the pagers, but there's nothing there that indicates how they're positioned, what the labels are (I want text, rather than numbers), etc.

Comment: The value you enter for the 'pager' option is a selector for where the links go. How they're styled depends on how good you are with CSS. Replacing them with links, or inline images, may be possible with CSS3 but a jQuery loop could probably do the job just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, check out [Easy Accordian](http://www.madeincima.it/en/articles/resources-and-tools/easy-accordion-plugin/).

[Demonstration.](http://www.madeincima.it/download/samples/jquery/easyAccordion/)

[image]

Comment: Well, we don't want the bars to slide over to the other side when the image is changed; the bars should stay where they are; the image should change in place. That's the main reason I skipped the accordion plugins. But I'll look at it; maybe there's a setting that would allow that.

Comment: Nope; there doesn't appear to be a way to do that. Thanks, though.

Comment: @EmmyS: This plugin is very flexible and customizable, you can always modify it too as per you needs. BTW, that is the only best alternative I know of to SlideDeck :) Let's see if there are others as well :)